# For SQL Recursive CTEs, why doesn't it reference the anchor member again each time it 'loops'? Why does the anchor member only gets 'called' once?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I was looking at the cte explnation on https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/

and a visual explanation at : https://277dfx2bm2883ohl6u2g3l59-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Parts-of-A-Recursive-Common-Table-Expression-1024x357.png

Wouldn't the anchor member be called again creating unnecessary lines?

Comment: Hmm. https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/ if you read a bit further there is a statement that When this query is run the Anchor Member is run once and its derived rows combined, via the UNION ALL, with the Recursive Member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, I think you're assuming that the behaviour of the recursive CTE should be a natural consequence of the syntax - it says "UNION", so it should behave like a normal union, and be re-executed for each iteration.

But that's not really how SQL works: recursive CTEs behave how they do because that's what the spec says they should do. The syntax could have used a different keyword instead, like `WITH RECURSIVE foo AS (ANCHOR=(SELECT blah...) CONTINUATION=(SELECT whatever...) UNIQUEROWS=TRUE)` and the language definition would simply say "execute the anchor once, and the continuation multiple times, then remove duplicates if required".

Language designers like to reuse keywords for similar concepts because it means fewer reserved words, and helps users remember some concepts, like `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`, but that doesn't mean the keywords mean precisely the same thing in different scenarios. In the case of a recursive CTE, the two expressions joined by UNION are really the separate anchor and continuation expressions like in my imaginary syntax above; the UNION keyword is just there to separate them, and you can change it to UNION ALL to turn off the deduplication step.

Comment: Alright I guess I have to accept the way it is and move on ... sometimes I overthink and I 'step' through it as if it were a python/MATLAB code

Comment: As in I still do not understand why it behaves as so without having to run the duplication of anchor member ...

Comment: @DCH SQL is not the most beautifully designed language, and some of its syntax is a bit illogical. As far as "stepping through", how about imagining that the "union" keyword was the beginning of a"while" loop: the code before it is executed once, and the code after is executed zero to many times. There really isn't a "why" beyond that, other than "because it's useful".

Comment: This has been breaking my brain, @IMSoP your explanation makes sense. But the CTE logic is ridiculous for SQL newbies